# Show that the vector $(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})$ is perpendicular to the plane

Tags: vectors

Problem: Show that the vector $(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})$ is perpendicular to the plane through the extremities of the vectors $\vec{b}\times \vec{c}, \vec{c}\times \vec{a}$ and $\vec{a}\times \vec{b}$.

Comment: Please add more context to your Question.  How did the problem arise?  Why is it important to you?  Have you identified any missing assumptions needed to make the problem well defined?  In general mere problem statement is discouraged, as Readers will want to see you've digested the meaning of the problem enough to appreciate the effort required to articulate a good Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: To show that $\vec v$ is orthogonal to the plane through $\vec A$, $\vec B$, and $\vec C$, you must show it is orthogonal to each of the vectors $\vec B-\vec A$ and $\vec C - \vec A$. (Why?)

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Reason  $\vec B-\vec A$ and $\vec C-\vec A$ lie on the plane. @TedShifrin

Comment: Well, on the plane parallel to it passing through the origin, and they span that plane.